# c++ initialize a map of maps more nicely

Tags: c++, dictionary, initialization

I have just started learning c++ today and am having a hard time finding an elegant way to initialise a map of maps. At the moment, the horrible method is:

```
typedef std::map < char, map < char, int > >  terribly_initialised_map;
```

and then

```
terribly_initialised_map plz_help;
plz_help['m']['e'] = 1;
....
...
..
.
```

There must be a better way?

Comment: Could you explain what's so horrible here, and what you expect from a better solution ?

Comment: ok: for a map of strings you can do it in a single line via {} notation. Using this way makes defining constant global variables more clumsy / tricky (may be wrong here but i am inexperienced). Further, For large maps it is pretty clumsy

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In C++11, it's a lot easier:

```
map_type someMap{
    {'m', {
        {'e', 1},
        {'f', 2}
    }},
    {'a', {
        {'b', 5}
    }}
};
```

This makes use of list initialization, using `std::map`'s list constructor (the one that takes a `std::initializer_list<std::pair<Key, Value>>`). The pairs can also be list initialized with the two stored values.

In C++03, you can do decently well with `boost::map_list_of`, but it might not be much better than what you have for nested maps, especially with the outer call needing to be a specific `list_of` call to eliminate an ambiguity:

```
using boost::assign::list_of;
using boost::assign::map_list_of;
map_type someMap = 
    list_of<map_type::value_type>
    ('m', 
        map_list_of
        ('e', 1)
        ('f', 2)
    )
    ('a', 
        map_list_of
        ('b', 5)
    )
;
```

Comment: The braces are mismatched.

Comment: do you have any docs on this - my internet search could not find anything

Comment: still getting expected ';' after top level declarator. Is this due to my c++ version?

Comment: @user3684792, I added some explanation. You can add this to your own classes if you wish, but the standard containers all made good use of it, as well as finally being able to just `return {blah};` instead of saying the type again. What I currently have in my answer compiles with Clang, though. Make sure you have C++11 support enabled (`-std=c++11`) and the compiler supports uniform initialization and initializer lists.

Comment: ah, the eclipse i dl'd didn't have this supported and I was running through the ide. ty